# Is it possible to change the "relativeHeight" or Z-order of an inline object in Word by altering the OOXML?

Tags: javascript, office-js, openxml, word-addins

I'm creating a Word Web add-in using office.js.

I tag few objects in source Word file using content controls. I'm insert a rectangle object on top of the source Word file. My goal is to bring few of the objects(tagged using content control) above the inserted rectangle.

I'm parsing the OOMXL of the Word document and trying to bring a tagged objects in front of this page-sized rectangle shape object that I placed above all previous objects in the source document.

For floating objects, I'm able to modify the "relativeHeight" greater than that of the rectangle, I manage to bring the object in front.

However, inline objects do not have this "relative property"? Manually, in MS Word, I'm able to change the layout of inline object to "in front of text" and this object shows up with an anchor having "relativeHeight" property.  [image]

Difference in OOXML:
Inline object

```
<w:drawing>
   <**wp:inline** distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="728024E4" wp14:editId="43DF6D69">
   ...
   </wp:inline>
</w:drawing>
```

Floating object

```
<w:drawing>
   <wp:**anchor** distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251659264" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="728024E4" wp14:editId="0AFA4E26">
   <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
      <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
         <wp:posOffset>533400</wp:posOffset>
      </wp:positionH>
      <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
         <wp:posOffset>-1905</wp:posOffset>
      </wp:positionV>
      ...
   </wp:anchor>
</w:drawing>
```

As you can see, inline changes to anchor and some position information is added automatically. I would like to know, how can I achieve this by altering the OOXML for any inline object.

Comment: is `<wp:inline>` only one tag? There is nothing inside the tag to separate the icons? Also, is the image you posted "Expected" or "Unexpected" behavior? I think you write it in your explanation, but it is easier to understand if we can see the difference visually.

Comment: @John: <wp:inline> tag refers to the inline drawing object. I have deleted the tags inside the inline tag with three dots. The image is just to describe how I changed the layout from inline. The difference in OOXML for the objects before/after layout  modification is given. I need to be able to do this inline to floating conversion programmatically in order to manipulate the z-order to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Inline objects, by definition, are treated as text. A shape, if it is inline, can be considered as a text character. Thus, you cannot put a text character in front of or behind the other text. For example, suppose you have a document that contains only three characters: "ABC", how can you put the character 'B' behind or in front of the other two characters? Thanks!